# Notificação push do Google Cloud Messaging demora muito para ser entregue

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Tenho um aplicativo semelhante aos apps de táxi (99Táxis,Easy Táxi, Uber), nele uso o Google Cloud Messaging para enviar os alertas de novas corridas, porém às vezes a latência na entrega da mensagem é grande, ou às vezes o alerta nem chega. Gostaria de saber se existe uma outra solução que eu possa adotar para o problema.

Comment: Na versão do(a) profissional ou do(a) cliente?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida na do Profissional

Comment: Já tivemos esse problema também. Parece que é algo comum. Isso acontece porque a conexão com o servidor do GCM foi cortada (provavelmente pela operadora ou pelo roteador). Até que o serviço do GCM peça uma nova conexão, o que acontece em [até 28 minutos](https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/). O que todo mundo faz é simplesmente largar o GCM e partir pra outra coisa que mantenha uma conexão própria do aplicativo com o servidor. Conhece o FireBase?

Comment: Não conheço não @PabloAlmeida

Comment: É como se fosse um BD (NoSQL) na nuvem que avisa os interessados de modificações em algum conteúdo dele. Você pode configurar o aplicativo do(a) profissional para responder a mudanças em "tabelas" específicas, como, por exemplo,  corridas não-atendidas. O feedback é instantâneo. O único porém é que o aplicativo precisa estar aberto (ou um serviço estar rodando), mas, como é no do(a) profissional, isso certamente é o caso. Dê uma olhada no site deles pra ver como funciona. É bem fácil criar um HelloWorld. Também é um serviço do Google.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação @PabloAlmeida, irei dar uma estudada, quanto ao consumo de bateria, sabe dizer se e tão eficiente quanto o push?

Comment: Provavelmente não. A questão não é push e sim o push do GCM. Os dois usam a mesma tecnologia (conexão permanente). O que diferencia é que o Firebase é otimizado para velocidade, então provavelmente vai gastar mais bateria. Mas, mesmo assim, é muito menos do que ficar fazendo _polling_ e muito mais rápido.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado novamente

Comment: pessoal iniciei meus estudos no firebase, e estou com problemas para conseguir enviar msg direto da aplicação, em todo lugar que pesquisei ate agora na internet, ngm ensina, a unica coisa que consegui foi mandar a notificação pelo console, porem em minha aplicação o usuário cria um evento com data e hora, portanto a notificação tem que ser criada junto com a ação do usuário, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço